# Send parameters with ajax call from jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, parameter-passing

I want to load data into a jquery datatable with ajax. Also I want to send parameters to the function that pulls the data from the database.

So what I want to do:

```
$('#datatables').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/results/load-results",
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "quizid": quizid, "questionid": qid } );
    }
} );
```

I want to so send the quizid and questionid and use them in my function. How can I pull them in my function? Tried $_GET but didn't work ..

Comment: Have you read this? http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6600/question-about-fnserverparams/p1 (TLDR: are you running version 1.8.2?)

Comment: Ok, but my questions is: how can I get these variables in my php function?

Comment: Have you tried dumping `GET` and/or `POST` vars in your php script (`load_results`) to see what values you have?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Format must be

```
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
      aoData.push( { "name": "quizid", "value": quizid },{ "name": "questionid", "value": qid } );
},
```

Comment: well how about if datatable has filtering multiple columns send variable by onclick, thanks